# Getting unexpected `TokenAccountNotFoundError` while creating a new Associated Token Account

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account

I am creating an ATA by the following code:

```
export const createAta = async (mint: web3.PublicKey, keyPair: web3.Signer) => {
  const { connection } = useWorkspace();
  try {
    const ata = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      keyPair,
      mint,
      keyPair.publicKey
    );
    return ata.address;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to create ATA: ${err}`);
  }
};
```

Here is the connection from the `useWorkspace`.

```
...
 const cluster = clusterApiUrl("devnet");
 const connection = new Connection(cluster, "max");
...
```

I don't understand why the code is failing with
`Error: Unable to create ATA: TokenAccountNotFoundError`

After looking at the code from [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L35) and [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7/token/js/src/state/account.ts#L86), I am unable to figure out from where the error is originating.

Thanks for the help

*EDIT*:
This is what I am doing ->

```
const initializerTokenAccount = await createAta(mint, userKeypair);
```

`mint` is the address of the mint and `userKeypair` is fetched from a function with the following signature ->

```
  async getKeypair(
    id: string
  ): Promise<{ secretKey: Uint8Array; publicKey: web3.PublicKey }> {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7/token/js/src/state/account.ts#L93 it seems like it would occur if the account info is not found immediately after creation, are you able to check in the explorer if it indeed worked or not?

Comment: Are you sure the `keyPair` that you are passing in is a `SystemAccount`, i.e. a regular wallet account?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at first glance. However it really depends what you are passing in.

Comment: @BryonM I have added additional information in the question

Comment: @CeNiEi With the given information I don't see how you would be catching a TokenAccountNotFoundError. If you throw together a small repo duplicating the problem I would be happy to help debug further.